# How can I get page timings for a SPA in Google Analytics using GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, marionette, google-tag-manager

I've been wresteling with this a few days and can't really find any good information on it. I am a novice with respect to Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager.

I have a client website which is a Single Page Application using Marionette. The client would like timings on how long it takes to load different pages in the application, specifically they want to know what pages to focus on for optimizations. They also want more analysis on user interaction in GA.

I've installed the google tag manager and setup the page view tag to show the individual page paths via the History trigger properly as described here:
https://www.pmg.com/blog/tracking-single-page-web-apps-google-tag-manager-analytics/

That is working fine, I can see the history fragments/page paths in GA.

The problem is when I go to Page Timings in the Behavior reports in GA all the timings are 0. Avg page load, server load, etc.

I've tried installing a page timing recipe from Luna Metrics:
https://www.lunametrics.com/labs/recipes/page-load-timing/

This did not work as the custom javascript in it depended on window.performance which after some research does not appear to work well for SPAs.

```js
function() {
  var timing = window.performance.timing;
  var ms = timing.loadEventStart - timing.navigationStart;

  return Math.round(ms / 100) / 10;  
}
```

I've also tried setting the siteSpeedSampleRate to 100 in the PageView tag for google analytics. This appears to have had no affect either.

i've also been messing with the tags and using the GTM preview and GA Debug and I can see the custom timings being set but with the same value on every subsequent link click (Its using the same page load value on the initial page load I think) which is why I don't think window.performance is an option here.

I've not been able to find any definitive way to get google analytics to track page timings for an SPA and would love any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just needed to be a little patient after the siteSpeedSampleRate change. That seems to have resolved the timing issues for me.